# Can one use SSL certificates for user authentication to websites?

Tags: security, browser, website, ssl

I hear that it is possible to create SSL certificates and use them instead of password authentication. Is this true and how to do it? And do all SSL enabled sites allow this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You do it the same way you create any other SSL certificate, you just include the additional purpose. However, almost no SSL enabled sites allow this because it's difficult to figure out the right policy without your own PKI. If you have your own PKI though, it works great.

Comment: Thanks... Can you direct me to a how to? Let's say I want to use this with gmail - how would I go about it?

Comment: You can't. Gmail doesn't offer it. As I said, almost no SSL enabled sites allow this. The exception would be entities that have their own PKI, like [StartSSL](https://auth.startssl.com/) (link will not work unless you have a StartSSL client certificate).